# Using Ethernet and Wireless Network on Windows Server

Tags: wireless-networking

I am having some trouble connecting to my server.  I have a headless NAS connected to my router through ethernet which *doesn't* have connection to the internet. But I also have a wireless USB dongle connected to the server to pick up another network that *does* have internet.

So my question is: How can I prioritize the wireless connect to connect to the internet while using the ethernet connection to login and control the headless server?

Can I connect and utilize both connections?

Comment: which version of windows server?

Answer (score 1):

It's odd.  You say the wired connection and the wireless connection are on TWO different networks?  But you can login using the wireless connection?  It sounds like one big network to me.

The most surefire method is to just address the wired connection by IP address.

Another method is to turn off NetBIOS on the wireless connection(on the NAS). That way your netBIOS broadcasts aren't answered.  While not a fool proof method, it doesn't require that you change your usage pattern. While you are at it, turn off the File and Printer sharing protocol on the wireless connection.

Lastly, you could just hardcode the NAS's wired connection into your computer's local HOST file.

Answer (score 0):

It really would have been helpful if you had said, I have a server at x.x.x.x using x adapter with a default gateway of x.x.x.x, and it connects to the NAS but not the Internet. And I have a wireless adapter with y.y.y.y, with a gateway of y.y.y.y and it connects to the Internet and the corporate network. Ans how they ALL are physically connected. It is really hard to get a hand on what you really have. So I am kind of guessing, so I will give you three things to look at.

First, you could just take out the default gateway on that connection which connects to the NAS but not the Internet. Even if they are on the same x.x.x.x network, the LAN traffic should attempt to use the faster Interface, and other traffic will have no choice but to use the Wireless interface to get to the network.

You can combine this by changing the metric of the LAN to 1, and Wireless to 2 to guarantee that it gives priority to the LAN (even if it should by default).

[image]

Lastly you can look in your network connections Control Panel applet, and go to Advanced>Advanced Settings, and play with the binding order. I cannot be more specific since I have no idea what your configuration really is.

Comment: I've always thought the metrics were used to decide which **gateway** to use.  Notice when you use the "route" command, it shows metrics.

Comment: @surfasb If you hit F1 for help it reads: "Automatic metric specifies whether TCP/IP automatically calculates a value for an interface metric that is based on the speed of the interface. The highest-speed interface has the lowest interface metric value." 

"Interface metric provides a location for you to type a value for the interface metric for this network connection. A lower value for the interface metric indicates a higher priority for use of this interface." So in this case, it would use the LAN connection despite not having a gateway, but when it needed a gateway, it would go to the

Comment: @surfasb wireless because it would have no choice. Obviously, in practical terms, the connection you give priority to is going to usually have a gateway, so most times it is related in practice, but not what the metric is really based on. Metric in network terms is basically the shortest way to route somewhere, which is why you see it in a routing table.